# Convert a scapy "IP" type to "Bytes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, netfilter

I'm using python3 and nfqueue to modify packets on-the-fly.

### Background

Scapy version: 2.4.1

Python's NetfilterQueue ([PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/NetfilterQueue/)) has methods to convert packets to "scapy-compatible" strings/bytes and vice versa, these are:

- `get_payload`, that returns scapy-compatible **string** in python 2, **BYTES** in python 3.
- `set_payload`, that sets the packet's payload after we were done with scapy.

### Problem

After I use `get_payload`, I can use scapy's `IP()` method to modify sections of the packet pleasingly. However, when I'm done, I'm left with an object of type "IP", which I want to convert to type "bytes" (to be able to use `set_payload` on it).

### Code output while printing IP attrs

('nnnn' is the actual packets data in this case)

```
running...

<class 'scapy.layers.inet.IP'>

b'E\x00\x008\x82\x00@\x00@\x06\xba\xbd\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x7f\x00\x00\x01\xeaj\x1f\x91(\x02\xb9\xffq\xa4\xd6\xbe\x80\x18\x02\x00\xf2W\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n\xa8b\x11*\xa8b\x11*nnnn'

b'nnnn'

Argument 'payload' has incorrect type (expected bytes, got IP)
```

### Q

How do I convert type `scapy.layers.inet.IP` to type "bytes" in python3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the source code, you can either call [build](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/8cefb5a3c6fc63457122283cfb02108948bd9ff7/scapy/packet.py#L606) method or you can pass your `IP` object to `bytes` directly as `IP` [implements](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/8cefb5a3c6fc63457122283cfb02108948bd9ff7/scapy/packet.py#L491) the `__bytes__` dunder method:

```py
from scapy.layers.inet import IP

p = IP(dst="github.com")

print(p)         # b'E\x00\x00\x14\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x00l\x82\n\x0c\x02\x05\x8cRv\x04'
print(p.build()) # b'E\x00\x00\x14\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x00l\x82\n\x0c\x02\x05\x8cRv\x04'
print(bytes(p))  # b'E\x00\x00\x14\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x00l\x82\n\x0c\x02\x05\x8cRv\x04'
print(raw(p))    # b'E\x00\x00\x14\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x00l\x82\n\x0c\x02\x05\x8cRv\x04'
```